# Build failed with an exception gradle in flutter project

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\sajoy\StudioProjects\untitled1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\sajoy.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

i cannot find the error

Comment: Have you done `flutter clean`?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?